# Axios put request not working while post and delete are working on React

Tags: reactjs, json, axios, json-server

My Axios put request is not working while Post and delete are working perfectly.

Here is my json request code.

```
{"todos": [
{
  "id": "5fe3f4ca-193c-4170-83c1-cb5a19908601",
  "title": "Buy food for dinner",
  "completed": true
},
{
  "id": "f619466c-a016-4281-b584-7db2795d103d",
  "title": "Call Marie at 10.00 PM",
  "completed": false
},
{
  "id": "5fe3f4ca-193c-4170-83c1-cb5a19908602",
  "title": "Write a react blog post",
  "completed": false
},]}
```

Here is my put request code which isn't working.

```
axios
  .put(
    `http://localhost:3000/todos/${index}`,
    {
      id: todoId,
      title: todoTitle,
      completed: status,
    },
    { headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" } }
  )
  .then(() => {
    todoList[index].completed = status;
    setList(todoList);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

The put request is giving me 404 error. I think it has something todo with my URL maybe. I am new to it. Can you guys please help me out.

Comment: You are using `index` and `todoId` but I guess it should be the same or related

Comment: Aah Thank you soo much. It worked I am very grateful to you. But can you please elaborate the answer? Both of them has different value. Shouldn't index point out which array to work on?

Comment: I have no idea what index is but it seems like your own implementation not related to the json-server